# Does learning by heart improve memorizing abilities?

Tags: learning, memory, long-term-memory, short-term-memory

Some people around me believe that if you learn poems by heart in childhood, it will help you to memorize things better further. They say about improvements in memory in general: things like mathematical formulas, historical facts, and even to remember better conversations in real life.
I'm talking not about using some memorizing techniques, but about the ability to remember things better if you have "trained" your memory (short-time one?) by learning poems (not songs, not formulas, not stories).

I looked for answers on Quora, but they look like "I think" or "Researchers say" without any references to rated scientific journals.
Are there any scientific works on this topic?